# como puedo llamar a esta funcion?

Tags: nodejs

Hola necesitaria ayuda con esto, la verdad es que soy bastante novato en programacion y no se muy bien como usar las funcionas asi que agradeceria una ayuda!

```html
var Discord = require('discord.js');
var client = new Discord.Client();

client.on("ready", () => {
 console.log("Online");
});

client.on("message", async message => {

let prefix = "!"
const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();


if(command === "start") {
     var embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
       .setColor('#48f442')
       .setDescription(`txt`)
     message.reply(`txt`,embed).then(embedMessage => {
     var favor =  embedMessage.react("");
     var against = embedMessage.react("");
     startgame(against, favor)
    });

let startgame = function(against, favor) {
        setTimeout(function () {
          if(favor > against) {
       client.guilds.get(message.guild.id).channels.get("536028903458996225").send("txt")
     }
          if(favor < against) {
      client.guilds.get(message.guild.id).channels.get("536337360808312872").send("txt")
      client.guilds.get(message.guild.id).channels.get("536028903458996225").send("txt")
     }
        }, 5000);
    }

   }
})
```

Comment: ¿cual es el nombre de la función que deseas llamar?

Comment: el problema esta solucionado!

Comment: Entonces publica la solución.

Comment: cambie el codigo por completo, de todas formas estoy teniendo otro problema, me podrias ayudar?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/GqfJdyUi , aqui estoy teniendo error de count undefined, y no entiendo por que.